# What is the meaning of tag format which will AVOID duplicate entries in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web-services, rest

Was trying to understand the `Node.js` web API for `MongoDB` [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-your-first-application-mongodb-creating-rest-api-using-mean-stack-part-1) and it mentions that

> The `entryID` field uses the tag format to avoid duplicate feed entries

What is the meaning of tag format which will **AVOID** duplicate entries in MongoDB?

Comment: Dont think this has anything to do with MongoDB in itself. Looks more like it forms a unique string

Comment: @hyades So, what it is exactly? If it's not a **MongoDB** stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this field is from missing example in that page...